# running functions in thread or using thread in functions

Tags: java, android, multithreading

i want to know that should i run my functions in a thread or write functions code in a thread!
my mean is something like this:

here i used my function in a thread

```
...
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_disable_stable_mode);
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    function1();
                    function2();
                    function3();
                }
            }).start();

        }
        void function1(){
        //some code
        }
        void function2(){
            //some code
        }
        void function3(){
            //some code
        }
    ...
```

and here i used one thread for every function:

```
...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_disable_stable_mode);
        function1();
        function2();
        function3();

    }
    void function1(){
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //some code
            }
        }).start();
    }
    void function2(){
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //some code
            }
        }).start();

    void function3(){
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //some code
            }
        }).start();
    ...
```

are are they same in performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first sample code will be execute 
`function1()` and then `function2()` and then `function3()`

but

in second sample code will be execute
`function1()` and `function2()` and `function3()` simultaneously

they are not the same method1 different from method2

Comment: i think you can't ask this question because they are different things

Comment: but , if the functions are not using the same resources they will be same in proformance

Comment: thanks  ,my mean is not functions running priority,in fact my mean is if i use my functions in a thread block so do they run in a new thread?